# How to render form with class-based view?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-3.0

I have an index page:

**views.py**

```py
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

And I need to render form in this page

**index.html**

```html
{% block content %}
    <!-- Other blocks -->
    <div id="input">
        <form method="POST" class="text-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="submit btn">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Other blocks -->
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```py
class TextForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

There is [a topic about class-based views forms handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) but it is not clear for me how to render HTML with this form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you do not pass a form to the context. You can make use of a [**`FormView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) or other views that use a form like a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), etc.

You thus can define a `FormView` and set the [**`form_class`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class) to the class you wish to render:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import TextForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = TextForm
```

@PavelAntspovich: if it makes a `post`, it will automatically construct the form and pass the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to it, and check if it is valid. If it is, it will call the [**`form_valid`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) with the form as parameter. If not, it will call the [**`form_invalid`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_invalid). These methods need to return a `HttpResponse` (that is then the result of the view).

Comment: @PavelAntspovich: if it makes a `post`, it will automatically construct the form and pass the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to it, and check if it is valid. If it is, it will call `form_valid` with the form as parameter. If not, it will call `form_invalid`. These methods need to return a `HttpResponse` (that is then the result of the view).